# Name of customer with highest sale monthwise

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a sales table from which I select the total sales per month , highest sale , number of sale for all the months in the current year, using

```
        select monthname(date),sum(amt_c),MAX(amt_c) 
        from sales where  year(date)= year(now())
        group by monthname(date) ;
```

I want to also select the customer who has done the highest purchase , i.e the customer correponding to the MAX(amt_c).

amt_c is the purchase done by the customer,

Comment: what is the customer field name in the table?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention , the customer field name is cust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is a filtering join:

```
select  filter.mn 
,       filter.sum_sales
,       filter.max_sales
,       sales.cust
from    (
        select  monthname(date) as mn
        ,       sum(amt_c) as sum_sales
        ,       max(amt_c) as max_sales
        from    sales
        where   year(date) = year(now())
        group by
                mn
        ) filter
join    sales
on      monthname(sales.date) = filter.mn
        and sales.amt_c = filter.max_sales
```

For more approaches, browse the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag.

Comment: Awesome!!! this works smooth. Thanks man. Could u please give little explanation of how this work .Sorry if am asking for too much .

Comment: This will not take advantage of an index on the date field and will repeat rows for months where the amt_c column is tied between 2+ customers.

Comment: @CleanX: A `join` or `inner join` only returns rows for which the `on` condition finds a match between both the left and the right hand table.  So you can use a `join` as a filter.  The `max(case(...))` construct is a way to do pivoting.  You can find more examples in the [tag:pivot] tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
select v.monthname,
       v.sum_amt_c,
       v.max_amt_c,
       count(s.amt_c) as num_of_amounts,
       group_concat(s.cust) as customers
  from (select monthname(date) as monthname,
               sum(amt_c) as sum_amt_c,
               max(amt_c) as max_amt_c
          from sales
         where date between concat(year(now()), '-01-01') and concat(year(now()), '-12-31')
         group by monthname(date)) v
  join sales s
    on v.max_amt_c = s.amt_c
   and v.monthname = monthname(s.date)
   and s.date between concat(year(now()), '-01-01') and concat(year(now()), '-12-31')
 group by v.monthname, v.sum_amt_c, v.max_amt_c
 order by month(s.date)
```

This is similar to Andomar's answer however it provides the following benefits:

1. If your DATE field is indexed (it should be) the above query will use that index. You should not have criteria on a date field with a function applied to it. MySQL does not support function based indexes, so it is a given that year(date) is not indexed. date may be indexed, however.
2. This sorts the results by month # (1-12) but shows the month name.
3. In the event that the same 2+ customers are tied, this will list all of them, and show only one row for that month. You would otherwise potentially have 2, 3, 4+ rows for a single month in the event of a tie. This is done via MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT function.

Comment: The order by in the inner query is not useful.  The join on sales should include month.  And no database uses an index to range-seek for a an entire year, the table lookups make that prohibitively expensive

Comment: @Andomar That was a mistake, just fixed. However I don't see why you would think that an index on the date field would not be beneficial.

Comment: The database will only used an index if it expects a small number of rows (for SQL Server, it's about 100 rows.)  For more rows, the cost of going from the index to the table (a "table lookup" or "rid lookup") is too high.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia am not able to get the count using your query , count(amt_c) is not possible

Comment: @CleanX what do you mean? I just added the count to the select list if you want that as well. Otherwise, please describe why it is "not possible". Are you getting a syntax error, is the count that is returned not what you expect, etc.